# kubeadm init gives below error

Tags: kubernetes

Any Solution for the following issue?

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
            [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time="2023-01-27T16:42:55Z" level=fatal msg="validate service connection: CRI v1 runtime API is not implemented for endpoint \"unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock\": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService"
    , error: exit status 1
    [preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
    To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CRI such as (**containerd** , **docker**,**CRI-O**) it's not running

You should check it before initialize the cluster using:

> **sudo systemctl status {your Container runtime service}**

for enabling and starting the service :

> **sudo systemctl enable  {your Container runtime service}**
>
> **sudo systemctl start {your Container runtime service}**